# Object synchronization with GUI Controls

Tags: c#, data-binding, forms, binding, synchronization

Every time when I change some values in form controls, I need to set a property of an object or vice versa. Instead of writing some methods for each control, I want a general solution for GUI elements. I do not use WPF but only C# 3.0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All controls expose events that signal that their value changed. You can subscribe to it and change another control's value.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the object a field in your form. When the relevant event fires from a control, then call the appropriate operation on the object.

Alternatively, have a Presenter/Controller object that stores your form as a field. It could take it as a parameter in it's constructor. This presenter can then subscribe to your form's relevant events and act appropriately. You could go further with this and extract an interface from your form and program to that in the presenter instead which would help testing. Have a look at the MVP pattern.